# Memory allocation Error Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Error:Failed to allocate a 499698 byte allocation with 212762 free bytes and 207KB until OOM

```
public static Bitmap StringToBitMap(String input) {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question? The error message seems clear: the device simply doesn't have enough memory. So you should try to reduce the memory footprint of the application

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap StringToBitMap(String image) {
        try {
            byte[] bytarray = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytarray, 0, bytarray.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            Log.e("EWN", "Out of memory error catched");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

use this instead hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest application tag.